# Why does a 'long' data.frame take more memory than a 'wide' one?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have discovered that when I transform a data frame from wide to long, it takes up more memory! I was curious why this was? Does it have to do something with the size of the largest dimension?

Reprex Below

---

```r
library(tidyr)


nms <- c('uid', paste('cid', 1:1000))

df <- 
  cbind(1:1000, replicate(1000, rnorm(1000)))

colnames(df) <- nms

df <- as.data.frame(df)

pryr::object_size(df)
#> 8.13 MB

df %>% 
  gather('cid', 'value', -uid) %>% 
  pryr::object_size()
#> 24.1 MB
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the linked question. Please take a look at the answers provided in that post, in particular the answer by Michael Hoffman concerning the memory usage of wide/long `data.frame`s.

Comment: I understand that the underlying implementation of a matrix is a vector with dimension attributes. I also understand that a dataframe is implemented as a list of equal length vectors. What is not clear to me (or answered in the post) is why a list of a few long vectors should take more memory than a list of many short vectors.

Comment: On a simple example like this where the data is perfectly rectangular, it is of no benefit to have to store all the extra column/row identifier pairs in a long format. If however you have data where most `uids` have 1-2 values and then some outlier `uid`s have 1000 values, the wide format will be terrible as it will have to store 998 `NA`s or empty cells in nearly every row.

Comment: The `value` column takes up 8MB in the long version, that doesn't really change. But then you have a `cid` and a `uid` in every row, meaning you have a million of each rather than 1000 in the wide dataframe. You can save a little bit of space by converting `cid` to factor.